# Как в Microsoft Access получить доступ к хранимой процедуре?

Tags: access, sql-server

Здравствуйте. Как в Microsoft Access получить доступ к хранимой процедуре, которая хранится на Microsoft Sql Server 2003?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Microsoft Access программируют на VBA. Я составил такой поисковый запрос: "*vba call mssql stored procedure*". Google выдал кучу годных результатов. Думаю не имеет смысла приводить их здесь.

Добавить референс на Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.x Library можно в следующем окне. Щелкните правой кнопкой мыши по разделу References и найдите библиотеку в списке. Если ее нет, то ее нужно установить.

[image]

Comment: У меня чудным образом VBA не хочет находить ADODB!!! И не знаю, в чем дело. У меня Access 2010.

Comment: Вам надо добавить референс на Microsoft ActiveX Data Object 2.x Library

Comment: А Вы не могли бы более понятно и подробно описать, как это сделать. А то я Вас не понимаю, - Ваш уровень знаний выше, и я не знаю, как делать "референсы" на то, что Вы указали. Спасибо.

Comment: Я отредактировал ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, все ясно.